# Handling Boolean null

Tags: c#, boolean

I have a program that pulls values from the DB for processing. On one occasion I'm pulling a boolean field to state whether a lecture is being held or not. I'm using the following statement:

```
var lectureOn = row.Field<bool?>("LectureOn");
```

This works well for 1 and 0, but I'm wondering is it error prone for NULL values? And if so, is there a better method I can use?

Comment: You can easily test it, Check your table for any record with `null` in `LectureOn` and then see if you get any error in your C# when you try to load your record.

Comment: where is the logic that uses lectureOn?

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm wondering is it error prone for NULL values?

No it isn't, because you are using a nullable boolean.

Generally,

> A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its
>   underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

For further documentation, please take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).